# signal.alarm function with resolution greater than 1 second?

Tags: python, signals, alarm

I'm trying to build a python timeout exception that runs in milliseconds.

The python signal.alarm function has a 1 second resolution.

How would one get an equivalent function that requests a SIGALRM signal to a given process in, say milliseconds, as opposed to seconds?

I've found no simple solutions as of yet.

Thanks in advance for your input.

Answer (score 17):

Use [signal.setitimer()](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html#signal.setitimer) instead.

Comment: So I am curious why Python's `signal` module does not have an interface for `ualarm()`...just because `setitimer` can generate signals other that `SIGALRM`?

Comment: No idea. Maybe it's not available on many platforms or something. I suggest to post a question instead of a comment.