# How to time out python function after X milliseconds?

Tags: python, time, timeout, timeoutexception, socket-timeout-exception

I'm calling a function `A(i)` in python . I want it to be terminated if it executes for more than X milliseconds. I've looked at some ways of timing out including `signal.alarm()`, but they all take the time in integral seconds. I want to do something like:

`signal.alarm(0.26)  //time out after 0.26 seconds`

How do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - signal.alarm function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770711/python-signal-alarm-function)

Comment: Did you try the signal function?

Comment: The title of that linked duplicate is a little misleading. Try using [`signal.setitimer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.setitimer), which accepts a float.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Timeout function if it takes too long to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281850/timeout-function-if-it-takes-too-long-to-finish)

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the [solution I linked as a possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770711/python-signal-alarm-function), you could also use [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) to use [`ualarm`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ualarm) if your system supports it.

For example, on macOS:

```
import ctypes

libc = ctypes.CDLL("libc.dylib")

libc.ualarm(10000, 0) # 10,000 microseconds
```

Answer (score -2):

[singal.settimer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.setitimer) requires unix.
Else you can use [time.time()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time)

```
import time

start = time.time()
now = time.time()
while now - start < 0.26: # 0.26 seconds
   now = time.time()
print (now-start)
```

you can use a [decorator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators), put your function under the while loop or raise an exception when timer ends (and probably others).

You may have to [thread](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) the timer.